# QGIS - copy/paste symbology labels

Tags: qgis

I often have layer metadata like labels for each unique value in a categorical map in a separate file, like in Excel. Is there a way to copy/paste entire columns from Excel into QGIS (and the other way around)?

I have a layer. Let's say a categorical raster layer. I right-click it, 'Properties', 'Symbology', do 'Paletted/Unique values'. Then click 'Classify'. I now have a bunch of non-descriptive, default-generated labels in the 'Label' column. But I already have those labels in Excel.

I want to not have to re-type them like a caveman. So I'm looking for a way to paste what would presumably be (on the clipboard) a newline-delimited list of strings into QGIS.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on your process and needs, as it's formulated it seem that some join or relation could be the answer but it's hard to say

Comment: I have a layer. Let's say a categorical raster layer. I right-click it, 'Properties', 'Symbology', do 'Paletted/Unique values'. Then click 'Classify'. I now have a bunch of non-descriptive, default-generated labels in the 'Label' column. But I already have those labels in Excel. I want to not have to re-type them like a caveman. So I'm looking for a way to paste what would presumably be (on the clipboard) a newline-delimited list of strings into QGIS.

Comment: That more clear, unfortunately I don't have solution for you (my first thought using join would be good for attribute table but definitely not for raster symbology) hopefully somebody else will have a solution for you. As a side note it would be better to add your explanation the question body rather than as a comment

Answer (score 2):

Your symbology can be loaded by clicking on the three dots next to Delete All button(On the Layer Properties window, Symbology section) option -Load Color Map from File...-. The file must have extension clr as plain text.
Inside this file should follow the format:

```
<Value> <r> <g> <b> <a> <Label>
```

Example:

```
0 136 78 87 255 My Label1
1 162 239 95 255 My Label2
2 44 59 192 255 My Label3
```

Comment: Yeah I know, but then I have to maintain all my metadata in two formats - the original one and this custom QGIS format. I'd much rather just have an easy way to transfer between existing formats. In fact, I miss this in more places; e.g. the 'reclass table' for the Reclassify tool has the same problem. Anyway I figured I'd ask...

Comment: Is not so custom format, from Excel you can save any file as csv but separated by space or tab instead semicolon, and then change the file extension.